# Delegate in singleton won't work

Tags: objective-c, delegates, singleton

I have a singleton that downloads data from an exterior database (PTDatabaseAccsesser).
When all data has been downloaded the singleton should call on a delegate which is a subclass of UITableViewController. However, i get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[__NSCFType doneDownloadingData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
```

This is how I set the delegate to the subclass of UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [[PTDatabaseAccesser sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[PTDatabaseAccesser sharedInstance] delegate]);
}
```

The NSLog shows that everything is correct here.

This is the code from the PTDatabaseAccsesser that calls on the delegate:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self delegate]);
[[self delegate] doneDownloadingData];
```

The NSLog here however is showing that the delegate is of the same type as in the error message above.

This is how I create the singleton:

```
static PTDatabaseAccesser *sharedInstance;

+ (PTDatabaseAccesser *)sharedInstance {

    @synchronized(self) {

        if (!sharedInstance) sharedInstance = [[PTDatabaseAccesser alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)alloc {

    @synchronized(self) {

        sharedInstance = [super alloc];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

I have made sure that the singleton works by using breakpoints in the two method implementations above.

Comment: Are you sure that the delegate object is alive when you send the delegate message to it? To make things safe, you should nil the delegate when you dealloc your controller. This way you will prevent messages sends to Zombie objects

Comment: The viewDidLoad of the UITableViewController subclass is called before the delegate message is sent if that is what you mean.

Comment: @user957032 No, he means that the subclass is being deallocated between setting the delegate and sending the message. Either your singleton should retain its delegate, or the subclass should set the delegate property to nil before it gets deallocated.

Comment: @Lio You were right. I thank you kindly!

Comment: @ughoavgfhw You were right. I thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the +alloc seems unnecessary and is probably the source of the error. From what I can see, `sharedInstance` gets its initial value in `+alloc`, which means that your if-condition in `-sharedInstance` is probably never executed and you are calling a method on an uninitialized object. Try this code instead, which also happens to be more efficient.

```
static PTDatabaseAccesser *sharedInstance;

+ (void) initialize
{
   sharedInstance = [[PTDatabaseAccesser alloc] init];
}

+ (PTDatabaseAccesser *)sharedInstance 
{
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that now but to no success :/ thanks for the code though - will use it from now on!